# Unable to download object from Open Stack Object Storage( Swift )

Tags: php, openstack, openstack-swift

Some days before all functionality working properly but now when I am trying to download object from Open Stack Object Storage( Swift ) then it gives error as below.

> Unauthorized
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your Swift setup. But below are some reasons.

1. Did you source your swift related credentials weather you are using TempAuth or Keystone as  authentication backend.
2. Did someone modified the configuration file for your authentications system i.e changing tenant/user/password/ other info in case of Keystone.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have hard-coded your authentication key in your code?

There is a sample project (ASP.NET MVC but it's very straightforward) on my GitHub showing how to authenticate against OpenStack Object Storage, browse and download objects.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/mkarczewski/CloudCam/blob/master/SoftProTech.CloudCam/SoftProTech.CloudCam/Controllers/FrontController.cs).